# How to find out similarity degree of the two sentences?

Tags: text-mining

I want to analyze the guest's review text and the host's comment text in Airbnb.

I have some pair of text data(of guests and hosts).

ex)

```
  guest1 review with host1 comment
  guest2 review with host1 comment
  guest3 review with host2 comment
  guest2 review with host2 comment
  guest4 review with host3 comment
```

And then, I want to see the similarity or conformity of each pair of paragraph.

Do I need to extract the main topic word in each sentence?

Which text mining algorithm can help me?

Can LDA show topics for each paragraph? (not for whole text data)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add whatever you tried and got by searching in google or other sites so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. If you got stuck anywhere, then please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. Try Shingling sentences to K-Shingle: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html
or look at it in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling
,you can find the jaccard similarity between shingles of two sentences

---

Also take a look at Bag Of Words Model that map each sentence to a vector and you can fine the similarities between two vector(two sentences) easily by dot product of each matching word: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model